# Xorg not working after upgrading to buster

Tags: xorg, raspbian-buster

After switching to Raspbian Buster and rebooting RPi3 B+ boots into a shell. (I use the GUI so this is a bit odd) After typing in startx I get this error (I cutout a bunch of junk):

```
(EE) no screens found(EE)

(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file

xinit: giving up

xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused

xinit: server error
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have `xorg.conf`? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: Graphical GUI works for me on a Pi3B. Was this an upgrade or a clean install? Did you set up your monitor per https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md and/or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=24679?

Comment: It was an in-place upgrade to buster

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Where is xorg.conf located?

Comment: It seems that there were a lot of changes between Raspbian Stretch and Buster. The Raspbian folks have suggested that a clean install is a better way to go than doing an upgrade. Is it possible for you to build a clean Buster SD card and move your stuff over to it? That might be more expedient than debugging your current card.

Comment: That would remove many things that I have done that I cannot backup

Comment: @reesericci it's somewhere in `/etc/X11`, though if you don't know where it is you probably didn't create it. Can you confirm that the upgrade to Buster went smoothly (e.g. `apt-get upgrade` doesn't report held back packages), and post the contents of your Xorg.0.log (located in `/var/log`)?

Comment: Also, if you'll have to start from scratch, running `debsums -c -e` on your current system will give you a list of config files you have changed, in case "I cannot backup" means "I don't remember what to back up".

Comment: `Closing log file` -> That will probably be `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and should contain more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong answer. The top answer seems to be much better, but I won't accept it because I didn't try it.

---

I eventually just sucked it up and reflashed my SD card with Buster. Wasn't too bad redoing everything

Comment: This is so Windows98 ...

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem as well and got around it by manually building and installing the [fbturbo module from source](https://github.com/ssvb/xf86-video-fbturbo) after which I had my desktops back

When I tried to to the install the missing package via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo
```

This blew up due to the dependency on xorg-video-abi-23. Looking around with apt-cache I can see the currently install module is xorg-video-abi-24 and xorg-video-abi-23 does not exist. My guess is the version in the repository has dependency issues and will not install due to those problems.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not sure why "I don't have an answer I just gave up" is the accepted answer...

Comment: Had to compile from source `https://github.com/ssvb/xf86-video-fbturbo/wiki/Installation`

Comment: I can't accept the answer because I didn't try it. I'm not saying that the answer isn't valid @PatrickCook

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. My root cause was that I forgot to update:
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`
from stretch to buster

`sudo apt update`
reported an additional ~ 200 packages that could be upgraded.

`sudo apt full-upgrade`
completed without error, but alas, still no X server, still no display found in the Xorg.0.log.

But I was now able to install xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo

(It doesn't currently auto-upgrade because it's still marked "testing" in the repository as of 2019-10-12)

I also ran raspi-config to make sure auto-logon to the desktop was enabled (yes, I know, that's a bad idea!)

2019-11-04 Update

Check the contents of this file:
`/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf`

for

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin pi --noclear %I $TERM
```

Mine was missing `pi` and was causing my auth.log and syslog to fill up with agetty complaints.

Comment: After 'sudo apt update' apart from ~200 upgrades mentioned above, I had 2 errors as it was not able to resolve those addresses. But I still went ahead with full-upgrade and it worked for me.

Comment: I ran into the same thing.  I needed to edit raspi.list then rerun apt to fix.

Comment: I had to delete /usr/share/X11/xorg.d/99-fbturbo.conf (or rename) and then startx worked as expected.

Comment: remove xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo and then reinstall.  That seemed to get autologin to work again for me on my rpi3.